# Group by clause to get name of highest paid employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table Employee with fields dept, employee ans salary. I want a query to list Department wise highest salaries and name of the employee with that salary.

I know it is simple. I googled but found answers like this, which lists only the department and salary

```
SELECT dept, SUM (salary)
FROM employee
GROUP BY dept;
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. Not every piece of code you'll need can come from Google. Sometimes you need to think for yourself. Sometimes you need to _learn._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 supports `Window Functions` which help you get what you want.

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  dept, employeeName, salary,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY salary DESC) rn
    FROM    employee
)
SELECT dept, employeeName, salary
FROM   recordList
WHERE  rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/409d1/1)
- [TSQL Ranking Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: Returns duplicate rows if two employees have same salary(highest)

Comment: @slacker because in the query I've used `DENSE_RANK()` and it think which makes sense because two of the employees have the same salary in which in turn the highest one on the department, if you only want to get one  you need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` ex http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/409d1/9

Comment: @slacker: well, that should be the case and it's right as there could be two employees earning the highest salary. J W's answer is right in a logical sense.

Comment: Or else you can use `STUFF` in order to aggregate the names comma separated and show in a single row for every department.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM employee e1
JOIN (SELECT dept, MAX(salary) FROM employee GROUP BY dept) e2 ON
    e1.dept = e2.dept AND e1.salary = e2.salary
```

Comment: I am getting this error, how to rectify it? No column name was specified for column 2 of 'e2'.

Comment: What database are you using? MSSQL, Postgres, MySQL, ...?

Answer (score 3):

```
  SELECT e.*, d.deptname
    FROM employee e
    JOIN department d ON e.deptid = d.deptid
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM employee e_in
                   JOIN department d_in ON e_in.deptid = d_in.deptid
                  WHERE d_in.deptid = d.deptid
               GROUP BY d_in.deptid
                 HAVING MAX(e_in.salary) = e.salary)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do it.

```
SELECT E1.DEPT, E2.ENAME, E1.HIGHEST_SALARY
FROM
(SELECT DEPT, MAX(SALARY) HIGHEST_SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY DEPT) E1
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E2 ON E1.HIGHEST_SALARY = E2.SALARY
AND E1.DEPT = E2.DEPT
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from (select salary,last_name,dense_rank()
over (order by salary desc)
sal_rank from employees) where sal_rank <=3;
```

That's all... this is the output below:

```
SALARY LAST_NAME                   SAL_RANK
---------- ------------------------- ----------
 24000 King                               1
 17000 Kochhar                            2
 17000 De Haan                            2
 14000 Russell                            3
```